# Properly backup OS/Boot partition

Tags: grub2, partitioning, backup, rsync

I have two drives in a media server that two different sizes, so I can't run raid on it. However I would like to backup my OS partition so that if Drive 1 fails I can just swap them, update grub/boot partition and keep going without an OS re-install after updating FSTab and grub conf.

As you can see by this image I have the secondary drives OS partition mounted at `/bakroot`. I also have home on the secondary mounted at `/home2` and once a day I rsync home to that dir to back it up also.

[image]

What would be the easiest and best way to keep an OS backup on the secondary drive for this purpose? I've thought of just rsync but I've done it in the past and I know that a lot of files are skipped since they are in use.

I would like to do it daily, so I don't think that a partition clone will work, unless I can make it do that at boot time or shutdown time without messing up the flow.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a good rSync line for the most part using various posts from around the net to come up with a good copy format. This is what I have ended up using:

```
sudo rsync -av --exclude=/dev/* --exclude=/lost+found/* --exclude=/mnt/* --exclude=/home/ --exclude=/media/* --exclude=/bakroot/ --exclude=/proc/* --exclude=/sys/* --exclude=/tmp/* --exclude=/var/run/* --exclude=/var/lock/* --exclude=/var/cache/apt/archives/* / /bakroot/
```

I excluded `/home` because I already have that backing up to another partition somewhere else.

Then to restore I just switch out drives and re-install grub using these commands:

```
1. Boot with any live CD
2. Get a root shell and make a folder (mkdir ubuntu)
3. mount the root (/) partition of ubuntu (e.g. mount /dev/hdb ubuntu if you have two disks)
4. chroot the mounted partition (chroot ubuntu)
5. grub-install /dev/hda [1]
5. Exit the shell
6. Reboot
```

So for the time this seems to work.